# ProcessPoolExecutor with method as callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to submit a method to a ProcessPoolExecutor, but it doesn't run the method at all. It works fine if I pass just a function though. Any idea why this is and what I can do about it?

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=16)
task0 = executor.submit(do_thing) # works
task1 = executor.submit(foo.do_thing)) # broken
```

Comment: `foo.do_thing` is not going to do anything with the `foo` you have in your process, it's going to operate on another `foo` that was created by pickling your object then unpickling it in the new process.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything at all though. It takes a fraction of a second to finish, instead of the 10 seconds it takes when using a normal function. I have a class that I need to modify, and I'd like to do many of them at the same time. Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this, would be to use threads. If I understand your question correctly.

I think in your case threads would be more appropriate as they share the memory space in your current process. This is why, this would not work with separate processes, as they do **NOT** share the same memory space.

So the two toy examples, that first came to mind are as follows:

```py
# in case you'd like to operate on one foo multiple times
foo = Foo()
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for i in range(4):
        executor.submit(foo.do_thing)

# if you want to work on 4 separate foo
foo_list = [Foo() for i in range(4)]
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.map(Foo.do_thing, foo_list)
```

and for completeness a Foo class to test it with:

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__sum = 0

    def do_thing(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            self.__sum += i

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return self.__sum
```

This is just one way of doing it of course.

Oh, and one last thing. If I remember well, it is recommended to use these classes within a `with`, as on finishing, this will shut down the Pool automatically, so you won't make the mistake of forgetting it.